# Databind Dynamic Control Type And Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controls

Im working on a method to make all my SQL Querys and then databind them to Repeaters, DataLists And so on...

```
protected void sqlQuery(Control controlName, String query) {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    try {
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(dt);
        controlName.DataSource = dt;
        controlName.DataBind();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        Label1.Text = "Error!<br/>" + error;
    }
}
```

Then i would call the method with my control name that i want to databind to.
Like:

```
sqlQuery(Repeater1, "SELECT * FROM someTable");
sqlQuery(DataList1, "SELECT * FROM someTable");
```

But that dosent work now since it dont know the control type when i just use Control..

So how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because `Control` does not have the properties/methods you require, and these properties are not defined on an interface or base control type.

Therefore you have to use something called  [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), this allows you to the call properties and methods (as well as lots of other things) that you require without having any compile time knowledge of these, of course if you pass in a control without these you will get a nasty exception and there is a performance hit when using reflection - but in your case it would be trivial.

I dont have an IDE handy but something along these lines should do it.

```
public static void DatabindControlFromSqlQuery(Control control,string query)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString(); 
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            var type = control.GetType();
            var dataSourceProp = type.GetProperty("DataSource");

            dataSourceProp.SetValue(control,dt);

            var dataBindMethod = type.GetMethod("DataBind");
            dataBindMethod.Invoke(control,null);

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: dataSourceProp.SetValue(control, dt):No overload for method 'SetValue' takes 2 arguments

Comment: Works like a charm, if you could explain what you are doing, that would be great :) couse it works, but i dont understand why :)

Comment: this is suboptimal solution since reflection is not needed - instead a cast to BaseDataBoundControl can be used (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer incorrectly assumes that `.DataSource` property can only be gotten through Reflection.

All ASP.NET controls that have this property are derived from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl` so you can write the code like this (without reflection, so it will be much faster):

```
protected void sqlQuery(Control controlName, String query) {
    // cast the control to the base class
    var controlWithDataSource = controlName as BaseDataBoundControl;
    if (controlWithDataSource == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Control does not inherit BaseDataBoundControl.");

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    try {
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(dt);

        // here reference the new control
        controlName.DataSource = dt;
        controlName.DataBind();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        Label1.Text = "Error!<br/>" + error;
    }
}
```

It might be possible for you to change the signature of your method to this class so you do not need the casting at all

```
protected void sqlQuery(BaseDataBoundControl controlName, String query)
```